# Footer not sitting correctly

Tags: footer

Can anyone help me rectify the problem of a website footer not sitting correctly?

I've had an answer but I'm not sure what to do.

I'm seeing a validation error:
Line 569, Column 6: end tag for element "div" which is not open
Also, there's a problem with the double use of an ID. You have 2 ID's with the same name footer:
Line 551, Column 12: ID "footer" first defined here
Line 563, Column 12: ID "footer" already defined
Try to solve these problems.

The website is www.planestrainsautomobiles.co.uk

Comment: Hmm, very interesting issue, couldn't lazy hover with firebug.

If you remove the fixed heights off #access and #wrapper you can alleviate the white space issue, however it breaks other stuff, I didn't go any further than that yet.

Comment: Can you please add the relevant parts of the code, because after your code has been fixed, the link will longer be a valid demonstration of the behavior you described, and thus makes this question difficult to understand for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

In line 542 you close one too many `</div>`, just before:

```
<div class="cute_profiles_sprite">
```

So your footer is outside your main container. Remove the `</div>`, and it will work. That is why, by the way, you have an extra `</div>` in line 569.

Also you are not supposed to have 2 elements with the same ID. An ID should be unique. If you need to reuse it, make it a class, so try:

```
<div class="footer">
```

instead of:

```
<div id="footer">
```

In that case, you'd have to change your `#footer` CSS rule to `.footer`